# Distinguishing between integers and doubles in a file

Tags: c++, vector

I'm quite new to reading and writing to files. But basically, I have an assignment where part of it requires me to determine whether a line from a file is an integer or double.

This is the part of the assignment I need help on:

> Open the text file and read it's contents one line at a time. Determine if the line read from the file is a double or an integer. You are to place the integers in a vector called `iNumbers` and the doubles in a vector called `dNumbers`. The vector `iNumbers` should hold pointers to the Integer class and `dNumbers` should hold pointers to the `Double` class. When you add a value to one of the vectors you should use new and call the constructor that takes a string. For example:
>
> ```
> iNumbers.push_back(new Integer("12.23"));
> ```
>
> Sample of the file:
>
> ```
> 12
> 20
> 80.5
> 99.345
> 70
> ```

From what I understand, I think I write code that will read the lines in the file and if they have a `"."` then those will be doubles, but I am not sure as how to start with that.
Any help as to how I should get started would be very appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Presumably you would need to examine the input, look for presence or absence of a decimal point.    You might also want to check what comes after any decimal point - for example, are `12.0` or `13.` intended to be an integer or a floating point?      Also, you almost certainly don't need to use vectors of pointers or operator `new` to create an element to add to a vector - pushing the value is enough.

Comment: `iNumbers.push_back(new Integer("12.23"));` – This doesn't look correct.

Comment: It is also no clear to me what makes a number an integer or a double. In the C++ type system, the literal `1.0` has type `double`. But mathematically, it is an integer. I think this question should be settled first before doing anything else. And as @Peter mentioned, the use of `Integer` and `Double` allocated dynamically doesn't feel very C++.

Comment: I think it is safe to say that a string with an explicit fractional field, even zero, is intended to indicate a greater-than-integer precision; hence, not an integer. "12" → int; "12.0" → float.

Comment: Possibly, Dúthomhas.   But part of effective problem solving is formulating a problem description that is complete and unambiguous enough that there is no need to preface comments about what is required with "I think it is safe to say that ....".

Answer (score 0):

Beware, in C++ (and not only C++), `1e4` is also double (with value of `10000`).

If this is not allowed in the task (and finding `.` in the number is sufficent), then I would create `std::ifstream` for the file, read from it using `std::getline` into a `std::string s`, then in the string I would `s.find('.')` and if it is to be found (the result of `find != s.npos`, pass it into `dNumbers` as `new Double(s)`, if such constructor exists for your class.

Comment: `1e4` being floating point is not unique to C++.    It is common to floating point I/O in almost all programming languages.

Comment: @Peter, I know, but this question is strictly about c++'s doubles. However, I'll edit my answer so that it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward way you could accomplish this task:

- read from the stream using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
- use [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) and [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) with this string as the parameter to determine the type - if they throw `std::invalid_argument` or `std::out_of_range`, conversion could not be done
- `push_back` to one of the arrays, depending on which type was

Answer (score 0):

To be pedantic, in the general case the best way to figure out whether or not a string is an integer is to *try to convert it to an integer* without any error or leftover characters.

Here is a very simple method to do just that (for any type):

```
template <typename T>
T string_to( const std::string& s )
{
  T value;
  std::istringstream ss( s );
  ss >> value >> std::ws;
  if (!ss.eof()) throw std::invalid_argument("T string_to()");
  return value;
}
```

You can now test for any standard integer vs double:

```
int n;
double d;
try { 
  n = string_to <int> ("12.3"); 
  // it's an int
}
catch (...) {
  try {
    n = string_to <double> ("12.3");
    // it's a double
  }
  catch (...) {
    // it is neither integer nor double
  }
}
```

If desired, you can specialize the int types to handle things like `"0xF3"` by unsetting the basefield: `ss.unsetf(std::ios::basefield);`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is old, but I goofed on `string_to()`. [Here is a correct version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47148159/2706707).

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see that we are in the same class...

There is more to the assignment that you left out. We have our double.cpp and our integer.cpp files that include constructors that take a string as a parameter if you did your program correctly, that is. So the iNumbers.push_back(new Integer("12.23")); is basically saying "iNumbers" - the name of the vector, ".push_back" - the function that puts the string value onto the stack, "new Integer" - allocating memory for the type Integer, and "12.23" - the actually double value that was used as an example in the form of a string taken from the .txt file.

What you need to do is look through his lecture slides that include the content about I/O files and you should be fine. We even did an example in class.

As far as your basic question about integer and double types, its very simple and I have no idea how you got through the past assignments without knowing the difference, an integer does not have a decimal point and a double does. Now there may be a more complicated definition for an integer and a double type but for Stevenson's class this is the only thing you should think about. Forget what you learned in your math class about integers. The definition is not the same for this class.

Best of luck... 
See you in class
-C