# Check for Empty sstream

Tags: c++

I am wrote a function that can replace `cin` for integers and potentially doubles, that includes error checking capabilities. Using `cin.fail()` I was able to check for most cases, but that didn't cover the case where the input was followed by a string without a space. For example, "23tewnty-three." The following code accommodates this.

```
int getUserInt(string prompt = "Enter an integer: ", string errorMessage "Error: Invalid Input") {
    const int IGNORE_MAX = 100;
    int userInt = 0;

    bool isContinue = true;
    do {
        // initialize and reset variables
        string inputStr;
        istringstream inputCheck;
        userInt = 0;

        // get input
        cout << prompt;
        cin >> inputStr;
        inputCheck.str(inputStr);

        // check for valid input
        inputCheck >> userInt;
        if (!inputCheck.fail()) {
            // check for remaining characters
            if (inputCheck.eof()) {    // Edit: This is the section that I tried replacing with different code (made code compilable in response to comment)
                isContinue = false;
            }
            else {
                cout << errorMessage << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            // reset cin and print error message
            cin.ignore(IGNORE_MAX, '\n');
            cin.clear();
            cout << errorMessage << endl;
        }
    } while (isContinue);

    return userInt;
}
```

This code works, but the reason I am posting this to Stack Overflow instead of Code Review is because my main question is about why some of code didn't work as I expected. The following is what I tried in place of `inputCheck.eof()` in the previous code. My questions are what are the differences between the following code? Why didn't methods 2) and 3) work? and which method is preferred?

1. `inputCheck.eof()`
2. `inputCheck.peek() == EOF`
3. `inputCheck.str().empty()`
4. `inputCheck.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0`

1) and 4) worked as expected, but 2) and 3) did not.

**Edit:**
I believe 3) didn't work as expected because `inputCheck.str()` returns what was contained in `inputStr` when `inputCheck.str(inputStr)` was called. However, I have no idea why `inputCheck.peek() == EOF` didn't work.

If this is relevant information, I am compiling and running on windows through bash g++.

Comment: I recommend you read a little more about [the `iostate` flags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) and their meanings.

Comment: It would be way nicer if you put compilable example code, with out all the unnecessary noise. E.g. why 3. does not work is easy to check if you check contents of `inputCheck.str()`. For 2. I don't think `EOF` is what you think it is.

Comment: @luk32 I did not see this comment till after I made the edit.

Answer (score 0):

For every prompt you provide, you can expect your user to press Enter. Obtain input as a string, then try to convert. (Don’t try to convert from `cin`.)

Bonus: here’s a function to perform conversion.

```
template <typename T>
auto string_to( const std::string & s )
{
  T value;
  std::istringstream ss( s );
  return ((ss >> value) and (ss >> std::ws).eof())
    ? value
    : std::optional<T> { };
}
```

You’ll need C++17 for that, or to `#include <boost/optional.hpp>` instead.

Now:

```
std::cout << "Enter an integer! ";
std::string s;
getline( std::cin, s );
auto x = string_to <int> ( s );
if (!x)
{
  std::cout << "That was _not_ an integer.\n";
}
else
{
  std::cout << "Good job. You entered the integer " << *x << ".\n";
}
```

No more worrying about clearing or resetting `cin`. Handily perform some loops (such as allow user three attempts before quitting). Et cetera.